# Error while building an xtext project with ant: Generation of the Grammar classes fails

Tags: ant, grammar, xtext, temp

I am developing an xtext plug-in project for an eclipse application for my Bachelor thesis.

I want to do the 'Generate Xtext Artifacts' at runtime with an ant script executing the Mwe2Launcher class and do the generation in an temp folder.

I wrote an Activator to create in the temp folder a project folder and copy the mwe2 file, my grammar file and the ant script.

Executing the Ant script leads to this error:

```
osgi> start 360
gen:
 [java] 0    INFO  StandaloneSetup    - Registering platform uri 'C:\Foo-test'
 [java] 2461 INFO  DirectoryCleaner   - Cleaning C:\Foo-test\org.xtext.example.foobar\..\org.xtext.example.foobar\src-gen
 [java] 2503 INFO  DirectoryCleaner   - Cleaning C:\Foo-test\org.xtext.example.foobar\..\org.xtext.example.foobar.ui\src-gen
 [java] 3056 INFO  LanguageConfig     - generating infrastructure for org.xtext.example.foobar.Foo with fragments : ImplicitRuntimeFragment, ImplicitUiFragment, GrammarAccessFragment, EcoreGeneratorFragment, ParseTreeConstructorFragment, ResourceFactoryFragment, XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment, JavaValidatorFragment, ImportNamespacesScopingFragment, QualifiedNamesFragment, BuilderIntegrationFragment, GeneratorFragment, FormatterFragment, LabelProviderFragment, OutlineTreeProviderFragment, QuickOutlineFragment, QuickfixProviderFragment, JavaBasedContentAssistFragment, XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment, TypesGeneratorFragment, XbaseGeneratorFragment, CodetemplatesGeneratorFragment
 [java] 6253 INFO  GenModelHelper     - Registered GenModel 'http://www.xtext.org/example/foobar/Foo' from 'file:/C:/Foo-test/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/Foo.genmodel'
 [java] org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/FooPackage.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1112)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.generatePackageInterface(GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.java:467)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenPackageGeneratorAdapter.java:219)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:221)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:290)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:617)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:528)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.doGenerate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:144)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.generate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:211)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:81)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.LanguageConfig.generate(LanguageConfig.java:108)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:352)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:97)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:73)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:76)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:35)
 [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/FooPackage.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.createOutputStream(PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.java:428)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createOutputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:339)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.createOutputStream(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1440)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.ecore.CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor$IdFilteringGenModelGeneratorAdapterFactory$IdFilteringGenPackageAdapter.createOutputStream(CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor.java:39)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1104)
 [java]     ... 21 more
 [java] org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Model.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1112)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateInterface(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:123)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:106)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:221)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:290)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:617)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:528)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.doGenerate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:144)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.generate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:211)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:81)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.LanguageConfig.generate(LanguageConfig.java:108)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:352)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:97)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:73)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:76)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:35)
 [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Model.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.createOutputStream(PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.java:428)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createOutputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:339)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.createOutputStream(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1440)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.ecore.CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor$IdFilteringGenModelGeneratorAdapterFactory$IdFilteringGenClassAdapter.createOutputStream(CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor.java:73)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1104)
 [java]     ... 21 more
 [java] org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Greeting.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1112)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateInterface(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:123)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:106)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:221)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:290)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:617)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:528)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.doGenerate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:144)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragment.generate(EcoreGeneratorFragment.java:211)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:81)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.LanguageConfig.generate(LanguageConfig.java:108)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:352)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:97)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:73)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:76)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:35)
 [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Greeting.java' is unmapped
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.createOutputStream(PlatformResourceURIHandlerImpl.java:428)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createOutputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:339)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.createOutputStream(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1440)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.ecore.CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor$IdFilteringGenModelGeneratorAdapterFactory$IdFilteringGenClassAdapter.createOutputStream(CvsIdFilteringGeneratorAdapterFactoryDescriptor.java:73)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1104)
 [java]     ... 21 more
 [java] 6768 INFO  EcoreGeneratorFragment - Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating code data=[] [Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.foobar.foo.FooPackage failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/FooPackage.java' is unmapped data=[java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/FooPackage.java' is unmapped]], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.foobar.foo.Model failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Model.java' is unmapped data=[java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Model.java' is unmapped]], Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore code=0 Generating Java interface org.xtext.example.foobar.foo.Greeting failed with an unhandled exception data=[] [Diagnostic ERROR source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Greeting.java' is unmapped data=[java.io.IOException: The path '/org.xtext.example.foobar/src-gen/org/xtext/example/foobar/foo/Greeting.java' is unmapped]], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[], Diagnostic OK source=org.eclipse.emf.common code=0 OK data=[]]
 [java] 10385 INFO  JavaValidatorFragment - generating Java-based EValidator API
 [java] 13246 INFO  Workflow           - Done. BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 27 seconds
```

The ".java" file which are unmapped were also not generated. The whole "/src-gen/...../foobar/foo" folder is missing.

I guess this is the reason and what should be fixed.

I really don't know, where the problem is. I already had a discussion in an [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/839974/#msg_839974) there you can find the build.xml but for another project, also an Activator class to activate the plugin and do the copy stuff and execute the ant script, also you find the mwe2 file I use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your register your temp folder as platform URI in your workflow. Xtext uses the platform:/resource URI scheme of EMF. Therefore, the platform root has to be registered in order to define the path mappings from absolute locations on the filesystem to logical locations according the the platform path. You could try to copy the .project file, too. I assume that will help if you already register the temp folder as platform path.

Comment: I encountered the error message with my xcore file because my project was not in the workspace but 2 directories deeper... Setting bean.platformUri = "${runtimeProject}/../../.." did the trick. IMHO this is very a fragile approach!