# Maven tycho to point to local p2 eclipse repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, p2

I have a set of plugins in eclipse with a product. My goal is to automate the deliveries: passing automatically test, creating automatically features and update sites...I found tutorials like this one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercisetycho_configuration_parent and it works great on my personal laptop where I have internet but not on my work computer because I don't have access to internet. The part that is the problem is the configuration of the properties for the build:

```
<properties>
    <tycho.version>0.25.0</tycho.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mars-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars</mars-repo.url>
</properties>

<repositories>
     <repository>
          <id>mars</id> 
          <url>${mars-repo.url}</url>
          <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I want to point my url to my p2 repositories in eclipse repository and not on the internet. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

Build the features locally using `mvn clean install` in the features directory. This should generate `/target/repository`.

Then, in your product `pom.xml`, you can update the repository to point to this local repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mars</id> 
        <url>file:/C:/path-to-target/target/repository</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

A `mvn clean package` in the products directory should give you an assembly using the local features.

There are also a couple slight variations of this answer in the answers section over here: [Build local eclipse plugins using tycho pointing to local p2 repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000208/build-local-eclipse-plugins-using-tycho-pointing-to-local-p2-repository)